# Custom validation rules

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules

I want to create a validation to a form that resets the password.

I have a method that checks whether the new password are the same and have more than 6 characters.

I miss only one thing to check if given the previous password is consistent.

```
    /**
* Reset user password
*
* @return void
*/
public function reset_password(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'old_password' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();


    return redirect('/user/profile');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"?

Comment: I mean or how to check whether the specified password is the same as the ones in the database.

Comment: You know, I give the current password and I want to check if the password is the same as in the database.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: It's version 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\Hash::check($request->password, $user->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create new validation rule: [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules).

What I did (not tested):

```
// Somewhere inside your app service provider boot()
Validation::extend('notSamePassword', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return !Hash::check($attribute, $parameters[0]);
}
```

And then in your controller/place where you validate:

```
$password = 'password hash to validate with';
$this->validate($request, [
    'old_password' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed|notSamePassword:'.$password
]);
```